# Java Audio - Playing WAV files with stereo abillities

Tags: java, audio, wav

Can anyone show me an example of how to play wav files with the abillities to loop, pause, stop, start, resume, play only on left speaker or only on right or on both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [OpenAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAL) - it's very nice! :D I was using OpenGL so this integrated very well with it. :D